# Soundclound BBcode for Kunena forum

Tags: soundcloud

I use Kunena Forum 3.0.6 with Joomla 3 for a :usical website.

I need to add BBcode in Kunena editor, so users can share their Soundcloud tracks directly on the forum with something like [soundcloud]my-track[soundcloud].

SO I have this code for now in bbcode.php

```
'soundcloud' => array(
                'mode' => BBCODE_MODE_LIBRARY,
                'method' => 'DoSoundcloud',
                'allow_in' => array('listitem', 'block', 'columns'),
                'class' => 'block',
                'allow_in' => array('listitem', 'block', 'columns'),
                'content' => BBCODE_PROHIBIT,
                'plain_start' => "[soundcloud]",
                'plain_end' => "\n",
            ),
```

and

```
function DoSoundcloud($bbcode, $action, $name, $default, $params, $content) {
                if ($action == BBCODE_CHECK)
                        return true;  



                return '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/'.$content.'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
        }
```

This way it works but not with the complete url. For example, if a user wants to share "http://soundcloud/track/1234" , he must post [soundcloud]track/1234[/soundcloud].

I would prefer with the complete url between the [soundcloud] because that would be far more easier for users.

Waiting for your suggestions !
Regards

Comment: thanks. the soundcloud player loads in the forum but there is an error message : `url` parameter is not a valid SoundCloud URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function DoSoundcloud($bbcode, $action, $name, $default, $params, $content) {
    if ($action == BBCODE_CHECK) {
        return true;
    }
    $content = preg_replace('%^http://(?:www\\.)?soundcloud\\.com/?%i', '', $content);
    return '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/'.$content.'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I add it exactly ? I tried but get 500 error.

Comment: Edited post. Shouldn't throw an error, since it only alters the string.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the code you give but it seems to have no effect.

With the code below,it works but not if there are dashes in the url (and maybe other characters ?).

I guess I have to add something like '%^http://(?:www\.)?soundcloud\.com/?%i' but I've no idea how to do.

```
function DoSoundcloud($bbcode, $action, $name, $default, $params, $content) { if ($action == BBCODE_CHECK) return true;

             $content = strip_tags($content);       

            return '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url='.$content.'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it of been easyer to add this to Kunena's Core ? Soundcloud download mp3 soundcloudmp3downloader.com/en/

```
case 'soundcloud' :
            if ($between) {
            $task->autolink_disable --;
            $tag_new = "";
                $tag_new = '<object height="81" width="100%"><param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=' . $between . '&amp;g=bb"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=' . $between . '&amp;g=bb" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed></object> <a href="' . $between . '">' . $between . '</a>';
                
                return TAGPARSER_RET_REPLACED;
            }
            return TAGPARSER_RET_NOTHING;

            break;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).